# How to get first hour of today in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime

I need to obtain today's date but instead of current time I need the first time of the date.

WRONG WAY:

```
'4/7/2017 4:50:13 PM'
```

as result of `getdate()` function

RIGHT WAY:

```
'4/7/2017 00:00:00 AM'
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Select Convert(varchar(max), getdate(), 111) might work. Use varchar(whatever) you need

Answer (score 6):

How about this

```
        select cast(cast(getdate() as date) as datetime)
```